# Difference between 結論を[下]{お}りる and 結論する

Tags: usage

I have found a few example sentences showing 私は.....結論を下りる.  Meaning is: I Concluded.。。。

Can I use 私は....結論する instead?

Comment: Are you sure it was not 結論を[下]{くだ}す?

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. The sentence I believe had けつろんをくだすketsuronwokudasu 【結論を下す】which means to draw a conclusion.  I think that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

You'd use 「[結論]{けつろん}を[下]{くだ}す」 or 「結論づける」 for "to conclude", so for "I concluded (that) ~~" you'd normally say 「私は～～との (or ～～という)結論を下した。」 or 「私は～～と結論づけた。」

Comment: 「結論を出す」も使えるかも・・・